# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.csaminorproject.www.procompete.pojo.Category

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display the categories stroed in firebase database in a RecyclerView but I get this error

My pojo is as follows :

```
package com.csaminorproject.www.procompete.pojo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Category {
List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
public Category() {

}
public Category(List<String> categories) {
    this.categories = categories;
}
public List<String> getCategories() {
    return categories;
}
public void setCategories(List<String> categories) {
    this.categories = categories;
}
}
```

The fragment which has this RecyclerView is:

```
public class SelectCategoryFragment extends Fragment {

static AppBarLayout appBar;
static LinearLayout selectCategoryFragment;

private static final String CATEGORIES = "categories";

private DatabaseReference mCategoryReference;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter mFirebaseAdapter;

private RecyclerView mCategoryRecyclerView;

public SelectCategoryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_select_category, container, false);

    appBar = (AppBarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.appBar);
    selectCategoryFragment = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.selectCategoryFragment);
    ImageView hideFilterFragment = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.hideSelectCategoryFragment);
    hideFilterFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            appBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            selectCategoryFragment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    mCategoryRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_selectCategory);
    mCategoryReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(CATEGORIES);
    Category c = new Category();
    setUpFirebaseAdapter();

    return view;
}

private void setUpFirebaseAdapter() {
    mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,
            FirebaseCategoryViewHolder>(
                    Category.class,
                    R.layout.category_list_item,
                    FirebaseCategoryViewHolder.class,
                    mCategoryReference) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(FirebaseCategoryViewHolder viewHolder,
                                          Category model, int position) {
            viewHolder.bindCategory(model);
        }
    };

    mCategoryRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    mCategoryRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
    mCategoryRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mFirebaseAdapter.cleanup();
}

}
```

The screenshot of my database is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake - I was trying to reference the wrong node.

The reference to be passed to the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter should be

```java
mCategoryReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

rather than

```
mCategoryReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(CATEGORIES);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with a similar "users" node. It was solved when I used the correct reference which was a child node of a child node.

This reference caused an error:

```java
databaseReferenceOfFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("users");
```

Whereas this one pointed at the right location:

```java
databaseReferenceOfFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("users")
    .child("TtrYYdL5OQT7bF5fJaPDuEsbqj83");
```

Comment: Your issue could have been found quickly if you named the variable something more specific than `databaseReferenceOfFirebase` such as `dbRefAllUsers` for the group and `dbRefUser` for the individual user.

Comment: @samthecodingman, how and why? do you mean other developers would have found my issue if i had named my object this way? but i added tags to this post for this purpose.